# R foreach do parallel does not end after loop completion

Tags: r, foreach, doparallel

My goal is to do some operation on a dataframe as follows

```
exp_info <- data.frame(location.Id = 1:1e7,
                        x = rnorm(10))
```

For each location, I want to do the square of the `x` variable and write the individual file as csv. My actual computation is lengthier and has other stuffs so this is a simplistic example. This is how I am parallelising my task:

```
library(doParallel)

myClusters <- parallel::makeCluster(6)
doParallel::registerDoParallel(myClusters)

foreach(i = 1:nrow(exp_info), 
        .packages = c("dplyr","data.table"),
        .errorhandling = 'remove',
        .verbose = TRUE) %dopar% 
{
      
  rowRef <- exp_info[i, ]
    
  rowRef <- rowRef %>% dplyr::mutate(x.sq = x^2)
    
  fwrite(rowRef, paste0(i,'_iteration.csv'))

 }
```

When I look at my working directory, I have all the individual csv files (1e7 csv files)
written out which says the above code is successful. However, my foreach loop does not end
even if all the files are written out and I have to kill the job which also does not generate any error. Does anyone have any idea why this could possibly happen?

Comment: I tested it with a smaller number of iterations and I don't have an issue, I can't confirm whether it is related to the large number of files. You do have a missing comma in your packages lines btw probably not related tho

Comment: Thanks. My actual computation is different inside the loop where I am reading some data, running some calculation and then saving the output. The squaring of x is just for the sake of this example. I just wanted to check if this behaviour of foreach not ending is something anyone has faced?

Comment: I have the same problem and it's super frustrating. I put all this time into code that uses doparallel but this has steadily been getting worse over time. I have to now write results to a .csv, kill the process and restart r and then read the csvs or else it will hang for twice the time.

Comment: Also this looks like the same issue:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35878255/dopar-parallel-foreach-loop-fails-to-exit-when-called-from-inside-a-function

Comment: Also, I wonder if it has to do with data.table commands perhaps and some interaction between multithreading and parallel processing? I'm out of my element though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing something similar. I don't know the answer but will add this: the same code and operation works on one computer, but fails to exit the for each loop on another computer. Hope this provides some direction.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32631323)